# Should we consider number of surfaces in a disk while calculating effective data transfer rate?

Tags: memory-hardware, storage

Suppose a disk has

Number of surfaces: 8

Number of sectors per track: 20

Sector size: 4000B

Number of tracks: 10

It is rotating at 360 rpm.

So disk is reading data from one track at an instance. So I will only find for a single rotation how much data can be fetched & I will find how much data in 1 second.

In 60 seconds -> 360 rotations.

In 1 second -> 6 rotations

In 1 second ->  6*20*4000B OR 6*20*4000B*8

So should I multiply the number of surfaces. If I am not wrong, all the surfaces have separate R/W heads. So should I multiply?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about concept D.W sir.
My question is clearly written in title.
I do not want the numerical answer for it.
That is just for reference.
My question is ..."Are the data transfer rate of one disk with 5 surfaces and one with 25 surfaces same? Do we read from all surfaces at the same instance, if we do so then we should multiply it."

Comment: OK.  Are you reading from one track only?  Or from multiple tracks simultaneously?  How do you define effective data transfer rate?  Data transfer rate will depend on the workload.  P.S. Check the rotation rate; 360 rpm would be incredibly slow for a modern hard disk.

Comment: No you can take anything. Take any value. My doubt is "Can all the surfaces be accessed at the same instance?" While calculating data rate should I consider that data is coming from all the surfaces or from only one surface?

Comment: What do you mean by "same instance"?  Do you mean "at the same time"?  ("simultaneously"?)

Comment: yes. I am asking for simultaneous access.